# a short statement that consumes lots of CPU cycles

Tags: cpu, consuming

I'm seeking a(very) short statement(in any language) that can make the CPU busy for like a second or a half. **The statement should consume CPU cycles, not IO stuff.**

Comment: @KennyTm: usleep is not busy waiting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Psuedocode:

```
A = 2
StartTime = GetTime()
While (GetTime() - StartTime) < 1.0
  A = A * 2
```

Comment: My flippant answer was going to be `exec Outlook.exe`. Then I realised he only wanted to keep the CPU busy for a couple of seconds not about 30!

Answer (score 1):

Using java BigIntegers, you could try and implement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function.

That'll keep you going for a while.

Comment: +1 I thought of Ackermann, but even the tightest implementation is going to be more than "a (very) short statement". Mind you, I suppose asker also says "in any language", and I bet the J / APL implementation of Ackermann is about one third of a line...